# how to show back arrow for the child fragment toolbar

Tags: android

I have a main activity contains lots of fragments , the main activity layout like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.user.taiwandigestionsociety_v11.MainActivity">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">

//----------------------here is my toolbar------------------------
<include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainFrame"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header">
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

when i change page to next fragment , i want that fragment has a back arrow on toolbar , it can return previous activity , perhaps fragment.

I try to set the function on main activity:

```
public void setBackArrow() {
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.nav_icon_arrow_18x18_white);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switchFragment(NewsInformation.newInstance());
        }
    });
}
```

my switch function:

```
private void switchFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fragment, null);
        //transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

and i call it on the next fragment like this:

```
    @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list_fragment,container, false);
//try to let the fragment has a back arrow toolbar , and has the onClick to previous layout     
      ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setBackArrow();

      return view;
      }
```

i can switch to next fragment and click it back at first.

but i got issue is when i back to the previous layout , i loss the toolbar menu function original , void setBackArrow() replace of it , and Navigation Icon always is R.drawable.nav_icon_arrow_18x18_white.

What's the best way to let my child fragment has the back arrow and it can change to previous layout ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `AppCompatActivity` instead of `Activity`.

The below steps describes overall idea.

**onCreate()**

```
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
```

**Set below code once the fragment attached/switchFragment completed**

```
 DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
 drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
```

**onBackButtonHit()**

```
 DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
 if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
      drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
  }
```

**string.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="navigation_drawer_open">Open navigation drawer</string>
    <string name="navigation_drawer_close">Close navigation drawer</string>
</resources>
```

**mainLayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
       <!-- AppBarLayout -->
       <!-- Fragment holer etc..--> />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```